# Is the escape velocity of black hole greater than the speed of light ? If not, then why does light can't escape the black hole?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, black-holes, speed-of-light, universe, escape-velocity

I've heard different type pf answers for this qs and not really sure which one to go for.

Comment: Classically, the escape velocity at the surface of a black hole is greater than the speed of light

Comment: A nice way to think about it is that all the light cones within the horizon point inwards. I.e. to escape the black hole from inside the horizon you'd need to move outside your future light come, which means locally travelling faster than light (along spacelike trajectories). It also qualitatively shows why light can't escape.

Comment: We already have lots of questions on this topic, with great answers, eg https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/261650/123208 So you need to explain specifically what you don't get about those answers. Otherwise, your question is likely to be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can gravity affect light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/130552/how-can-gravity-affect-light)