# Gravitational Time Dilation Near Center of Gravity

Tags: time-dilation

Stretch your imagination a bit and imagine an almost empty universe with nothing in it but a very, very large asteroid (or an asteroid in our universe but in an almost empty patch so it's not affected too much by other celestial bodies).

I travel to this asteroid and I use some powerful drill and dig a tunnel to the center of mass of this asteroid.

Far away in another empty patch of the universe an atomic clock ticks exactly one second. Consider this the "proper" time interval.

The equation to calculate gravitational time dilation under the effect of a non-rotating object is

$$
\Delta t_{ 2 }= \Delta t_{ 1 } \sqrt { 1-\frac { 2Gm }{ rc^{ 2 } }  }   = \Delta t_{ 1 }  \sqrt { 1-\frac { r_{ s } }{ r }  }
$$

where $r_s$ is the Schwarzschild radius, $r$ is my distance from the center of the center of mass, $\Delta t_2$ is the time interval experienced by the observer and $\Delta t_1$ is the proper time interval.

In order to try to solve the time dilation using this equation while I sit exactly on the center of mass I have to divide by 0 because my distance from the center is 0.

Since that would be mathematically undefined, how long has passed relative to an observer at the center of a non-rotating and not very massive object?

I've searched for other questions but they use other equations, consider black holes, talk about the Earth, or have been closed due to poor wording by the OP. My curiosity is what this can tell me about how one would experience time at the center of an asteroid.

Comment: The Schwarzschild solution you give is only valid *outside* the massive body - recall that gravity becomes *weaker* when you descend into the earth, and is gone at its center, since the mass distribution is then totally symmetric around you.

Comment: @Arc676: like what ACM said, you've been distracted here by a black hole expression which isn't quite appropriate. See for example [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10089/gravitational-time-dilation-at-the-earths-center) where a couple of guys offer reasonable answers. Also see the green curve on Phil Fraundorf's [picture on Wiki](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Orbit_times.svg). That doesn't match the $\sqrt { 1-\frac { r_{ s } }{ r }}$ expression, because the expression applies to the black hole exterior, not a planet interior.

Comment: See also [the higher you go the slower is ageing](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69043/the-higher-you-go-the-slower-is-ageing)

Comment: I see. So is there a way to calculate time dilation from the interior of a planet (or more accurately from within the Schwarzschild radius)?