# Time dilation in the center of the earth

Tags: special-relativity, gravity, time, time-dilation

The time dilation seem to slow time in stronger gravitational fields.

Lets say we put a person with a clock in the center of the earth.
It will feel no gravity since it's pulling from every direction effectively reducing itself to zero.

Is the effect of time slow will still be observable?
In that case one can "theoretically" build a time slowing machine.

Comment: Of course , such a machine is theoretically possible, the feasibility and whether the magnitude of "time slowing" achievable is significant enough to be worth the effort is another question

Comment: Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/69048/123208

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation#Experimental_confirmation) has a nice [graph](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/Orbit_times.svg) showing time dilation outside and inside the Earth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the center of the Earth there would be no net gravitational force. This does not mean the same as no gravity. The center is affected equally by all of Earth's mass so it is pulled equally in all directions. So there would still be gravitational time dilation even though there is no net force to pull it more in one direction than another.

Comment: Rough, non-rigorous calculation that tries to blend Newton & Schwarzschild: set the gravitational potential $u$ to be $0$ at infinity, so at $r=R$ we have time dilation factor $\sqrt{1+2u}$ with $u=-\frac{GM}{Rc^{2}}$. At $r=0$, you can show $u=-\frac{3GM}{2Rc^{2}}$, so $\sqrt{1+2u}=\sqrt{1-\frac{3GM}{Rc^{2}}}$.

Comment: The differential time rate is ~3.48E-10, so over a century a clock at the centre of the Earth would be slow by ~1.1 seconds compared to a clock on the surface.