# General Relativity and Time Dilation

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, time

Is time affected by the gravitational force?

If so, what might be the effect on time at the centre or near centre of earth ?

Comment: Duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10089/

Comment: @jinawee: Did you flag it as duplicate of the right question? Because when I was flagging it as duplicate, it said that someone had said it was duplicate  "Why does space expansion not expand matter?".

Comment: No, I flagged it as duplicate of the wrong question. But there is no way to modify a flag.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you think that the time is affected by gravitational force ?

Yes, this is the point of the metric. As for your second question, gravitational time dilation still exists at the centre of the Earth, because time dilation depends on the potential, not the gravitational field.

Comment: The gravititation force is indeed zero at the centre of the Earth, but the time dilation is not.