# How much time has passed for Voyager I since it left the Earth, 34 years ago?

Tags: spacetime, time, space, relativity, solar-system-exploration

34 years have passed since Voyager I took off and it's just crossing the solar system, being approximately at 16.4 light-hours away. How much time have passed for itself, though?

Comment: 34 years. (If you're thinking about relativistic time dilation the effect is **very** small.)

Comment: I was - I've just found an online calculator for it. So I guess I can end my hopes we will ever be able to build a time slowdown machine that worked by orbiting the sun ridiculously fast, or something like that? A next question might be: why voyager 1 is so slow? What stops us from just accelerating more?

Comment: @Dokkat If you can't find the answer to that followup on this site, by all means start a new post.

Comment: Similar effect from different physics: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9921/voyager-local-time-dilation-caused-by-gravity

Answer (score 4):

Using those numbers, let's assume it has been traveling in a straight line at constant speed.<sup>1</sup> Then the speed is
$$ v = \frac{16.4~\mathrm{hr}\cdot c}{34~\mathrm{yr}} = 5.5\times10^{-5} c, $$
so we can see right away it is traveling at a negligible fraction of the speed of light.

Still, we can compute the effects of time dilation. The relevant factor is
$$ \frac{1}{\gamma} = \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}} = 1 - 1.5\times10^{-9}. $$
This is because the proper time experienced by the spacecraft is the time lapse we experience - call it $\Delta t_\text{Earth}$ - divided by gamma:
$$ \Delta t_\text{Voyager} = \frac{1}{\gamma} \Delta t_\text{Earth}. $$
The spacecraft's clocks have progressed just a hair under $34$ years - in fact, they are slow by
$$ 1.5\times10^{-9} (34~\mathrm{yr}) = 1.6~\mathrm{s}. $$

---

<sup>1</sup> This is not quite true, but the general result is still the same.