# Is time relevant to mass of the planet or the star the planet is part of?

Tags: general-relativity, astrophysics

For instance, if we travel from a planet in one star system to another where there is a huge difference in mass(neutron star) for both the planet and the star compared to the other system (planet and the star). Will time run faster in the low mass system compared to the high mass system.

According to a recent experiment even moving away from earth has created a time difference.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKwJayXTZUs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Voyager local time dilation (caused by gravity)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9921/voyager-local-time-dilation-caused-by-gravity)

Comment: Yes, but unless the surface gravity is huge (like in neutron stars etc.) you wan't be able to measure the difference unless you use very precise equipment.

Comment: Thanks, @Prof. Legolasov, what if we consider a neutron star?

Comment: If you're in a deep gravity well, time flows slower. That's a well-known fact which is mathematically described by General Relativity. What is your question again? If you're curious on how humans would perceive time dilation, give Interstellar (the movie) a go :)

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov - with fairly readily available equipment you can measure gravitational changes in time right here on Earth, driving up mountains. Standard lab-grade atomic clocks do it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

As per GR, what you are asking about is gravitational time dilation.

> > Gravitational time dilation is a form of time dilation, an actual difference of elapsed time between two events as measured by observers situated at varying distances from a gravitating mass. The higher the gravitational potential (the farther the clock is from the source of gravitation), the faster time passes.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation

We have experiments that already show small differences between clocks tick rate when the clocks are at different altitudes above Earth.

The clock closer to the surface will seem to tick slower (relatively).

In your case, the clock on the planet that has more stress-energy (contrary to popular belief, it is not mass, but stress-energy, and the difference of stress-energy between two points in space that creates time dilation) the clocks will seem to run slower, compared to the clocks on Earth.

So time will seem to run slower in the high mass (in reality it is high stress-energy) system, and clocks will seem to run faster in the low mass ((in reality it is low stress-energy) system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a difference . As we move away from the earth the clocks start ticking faster. This happens due to space and time being bonded and objects with stress bend space-time.